# Setting/getting fields of a class with an array: faster way than reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection

When I access my `Operation` classes from the outside, I am using reflection to set their fields with an array of values. This is because it lends itself better to automation purposes.

When accessed from the inside (see method `Calculate`), I want to use the fields by name for the sake of better readability. The number of fields varies between different classes derived from `Operation`.

Is there a faster way to do this than by reflection?

```
public abstract class Operation
{
    readonly FieldInfo[] inputFields;

    public int InputCount {get {return inputFields.Length;}}

    public Cacheable[] InputData
    {
        get 
        {
            Cacheable[] result = new Cacheable[inputFields.Length];

            for (int i=0; i<inputFields.Length; i++)
            {
                result[i] = (Cacheable)inputFields[i].GetValue(this);
            }

            return result;
        }
        set 
        {
            for (int i=0; i<inputFields.Length; i++)
            {
                inputFields[i].SetValue(this, value[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    public Operation()
    {
        FieldInfo[] inputFields = GetType().GetFields();
    }

    public abstract void Calculate();
}

public class OperationA: Operation
{
    public CacheableU SomeField;
    public CacheableV AnotherField;

    public override void Calculate()
    {
        DoSomething(SomeField, AnotherField);
    }
}   

public class OperationB: Operation
{
    public CacheableU SomeField;
    public CacheableV AnotherField;
    public CacheableW YetAnotherField;

    public override void Calculate()
    {
        DoSomethingElse(SomeField, AnotherField, YetAnotherField);
    }
}

// ...
Cacheable[] inputsToA = new[]{c1, c2};
OperationA opa = new OperationA();
opa.InputData = inputsToA;
opa.Calculate();

Cacheable[] inputsToB = new[]{c3, c4, c5};
OperationB opb = new OperationB();
opb.InputData = inputsToB;
opb.Calculate();
```

Comment: you are using 2 objects we don't know anything about

Comment: You don't need to.

Comment: What about the order of your members? The compilier guarantees nothing in that matter.

Comment: @thehenny: true, but in the reflection approach order does not matter, right? That would be a limiting factor for an approach writing more or less directly to memory. Is that what you want to indicate?

Comment: well if you need someone to do an analysis on what you have done then they need to know the rest of those objects as well. because your structure might not require reflection, and generally if you are using reflection there is other ways to achieve the same thing

Comment: @thehenny: ah now I understand - in the array the meaning of the individual elements is identified by other reflection based information. I have spared this for the sake of brevity.

Comment: @Neil: I guess the usual approach to incomplete information is to assume the most general case, isn't it? If I tell you something about specific use cases, you might optimize for the them, breaking the general case...

Comment: @oliver fair enough. but it helps visualize/understand what is trying to be achieved.

Comment: Those Cacheable base classes are a bunch of numerical containers (like time series, tables or individual numbers). The operations performed on them can be anything from simple multiplications, LTI filtering, fourier transforms and such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: Yes.

Longer answer: It depends. How often is this being done? If it's being done many many times over the lifetime of the application, then there are faster ways than reflection: either use expression trees (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/) or emit IL at runtime to do this.

However, the cost of compiling the expression tree (or IL function) for re-use is fairly high. If you are doing this once at the beginning of the application's lifecycle, or if the appdomain is short-lived (eg. console application that runs every few minutes), then the cost per access is greatly dwarfed by the startup costs.

Comment: Well, I could easily afford compiling something for a limited number of 'Operation' classes at application start. At the moment the frequency of the respective calculations is relatively low, so I probably don't need getting faster. But the project I am working on has suffered kind of scope creep several times, so now I want to be prepared for higher computational demand in the future and make the right design decision now. Can you give an approximate figure about how much more code would be needed to do it with expression trees? Two times? Ten times? How much faster would it probably be?

Comment: It's less about how much more code so much as needing to think in a different way. Though it is true that you will need more code to perform the same operations. As for performance, it tends to be several orders of magnitude faster than reflection, here's a relatively old comparison: http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2008/10/04/expression-tree-vs-reflection/

It also has some code samples, though the blog's formatting has changed and might be hard to read.

Comment: I have looked at the codewrecks link. It looks like an answer to my question, but I will have to wait until I find the time to implement it for my use case. I mark the answer as accepted anyway.

Comment: Do keep in mind that value types and reference types can be very different when you're dealing with some underlying data, especially if you go with emitting IL. If a code sample isn't working for you, that might be why.

Comment: Thanks, in my case I am only interested in reference types. But good to know that some Debug.Asserts are due.